# Creating a cron job with PHP and Apache

Tags: php, apache, cron

I have Apache running on Debian with PHP 5.4.
PHP-cli is installed.
My directory structure for the web project is:

```
 - /myproject
     - /src
         - /controller
             - getProviders.php
         - /model
         - /public
         - ClassLoader.php
```

I want to create a cron job to execute getProviders.php every 5 minutes. This is as far as I have come:
`*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myproject/src/controller/getProviders.php`

It doesn't work because I have a require_once in getProviders.php requiring ClassLoader.php, but he can't find it.
`require_once "../ClassLoader.php"`

getProviders.php works when executed via URL.

I'm not new to PHP development, but new at configuring the server around it.
What do I have to do to make it work. I'm guessing I have to set the include path, but I have no idea to what exactly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you requiring your file now, can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the require_once will always work, you could use `dirname(__FILE__)` + the path relative to the getProviders.php

In your case this would be:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../ClassLoader.php");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. But what exactly is the difference between your solution and my attempt of it?

Comment: When you call the getProviders.php via URL it automatically will use the directory it is stored in as working directory. But when you call the PHP file with cron, I think it will use the home directory of the cron user as working directory. With my solution it makes always prepending the directory of the getProviders.php to the relative path, so no matter what the working directory is, it gets the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

Create a shell script like this in /usr/sbin (For Example: getProviders)

```
#!/bin/bash -x
cd  /var/www/myproject/src/controller/
php getProviders.php
```

give permission

```
chmod a+x /usr/sbin/getProviders
```

in /etc/crontab

```
*/5 * * * * root /usr/sbin/getProviders
```

the problem is probably due to inclusions not in absolute value in the php script

Answer (score 1):

Change to the right workdirectory.

You could do this with the cd command or inside your PHP script with the [chdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) function.